# More than 1 instance of annotation not working in Acrobat

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I'm trying to add multiple annotations in pdf document through Acrobat javascript. However, only the first annotation is working if I include both. The second annotation only works if I include that one separately.

```
var spans = new Array();
spans[0] = new Object();
spans[0].text = "Links to: ";
spans[0].textSize = 12;
spans[0].textColor = color.red;

spans[1] = new Object();
spans[1].text = "http://www.example.com";
spans[1].textSize = 12;
spans[1].textColor = color.black;

// Now create the annot with spans as it's richContents
var annot = this.addAnnot({
    page: 0,
    type: "FreeText",
    rect: [50, 50, 300, 100],
    richContents: spans
});

var copy_annot = this.addAnnot({type: "Line"})
    annot.setProps({
    page: 0,
    points: [[400,490],[430,690]],
    strokeColor: color.red,
    arrowBegin: "Diamond",
    arrowEnd: "OpenArrow"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to change the variable name before setting the property

**Solution:**

```
var copy_annot = this.addAnnot({type: "Line"})
    copy_annot.setProps({
    ...
});
```